# Ao gerar planilha salvar a mesma no servidor

Tags: php, phpexcel

Olá, estou gerando uma tabela em Excel utilizando a classe PHPExcel, assim que gerava forçava o download, só que agora quero que ao gerar ele salve no servidor ao invés de força o download diretamente, não achei na documentação, a parte que força o download seria essa

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="planilha.xls"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: basta utilizar `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');` e em seguida `$objWriter->save(diretorio/planilha.xls);`.
O segundo parametro do **createWriter** é a versão que será salva, neste caso para arquivos .xls usa-se o Excel5, para salvar .xlsx use Excel2007.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, assim resolveu, igual a resposta do Guilherme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta remover o:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="planilha.xls"');
```

E trocar isto:

```
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Por algo semelhante a isto:

```
$objWriter->save('pasta/foo/baz.pdf');
```

Assim vai salvar em uma pasta no servidor, se quiser salvar e fazer o download ao mesmo tempo, pode usar:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="planilha.xls"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

copy('php://output', 'pasta/foo/baz.pdf');
```

Ou usar (não testei, mas a doc não impõe nenhuma restrição):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="planilha.xls"');
$objWriter->save('pasta/foo/baz.pdf');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado amigo.